# Matlab: How can I change the following program

Tags: matlab, filenames

I have 500 files .TXT, for example:

```
abc-1.TXT  
adfer-2.txt  
affd-3.TXT  
asxdcccc-4.TXT  
...
```

How can I change the following program to achieve results in order of numbers in the filenames:

```
Names = dir('MyFile\*.TXT');  
for i = 1:500  
    fn = strcat(['MyFile\' Names(i).name]);  
    ...
```

is there a way to make the loop on the numbers contained in the file names?
the problem with the above program is that I got results that do not follow the order of the numbers contained in the file names.

THANK YOU to everyone who helped me to advance in my work.

Comment: It would help if you gave the actual filenames and directories rather than make them up... that may give a clue as to why your code is not running the way you expect it to.

Comment: MyFile is a folder that contains 500 files, and i want to process them in numeric order.    
File names are not arbitrary.

Comment: You already created similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349519/what-do-i-have-to-add-at-the-beginning-of-this-loop). Why not to edit it to add more details or answer comments? The title is also very undescriptive. -1.

Comment: you have apparently two accounts at SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
names={'abc-1.TXT';
'affd-3.TXT';
'sdfg-33.txt';
'adfer-2.txt';
'asxdcccc-4.TXT'};

for i=1:length(names)
    [v1 v2]=regexp(names{i},'[1-9]*');
    numbers(i)=str2num(names{i}(v1:v2));
end

[B,IX] = sort(numbers);
names{IX}
```

The last line will print the names in the order of numbers. I guess you can carry on from here.

Oh, and you should start with

```
Names = dir('*.TXT');
names = Names.name;
```

Comment: The last line should be: names = {Names.name}'; Anyway good answer.