# Structure in Matlab (I can't find a proper title !)

Tags: matlab, structure

In my scenario, I have 100 nodes. Each time a random node out of them generates a data. I wish to record them in previously created files.

I have been using switch-case style to open the particular file associated with a node. However, it's clumsy for 100 nodes already and I need to increase the number of nodes. I was looking for a straight forward manner of opening a file based on node. I found bit hint here:

[Stackoverflow_a_year_ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349519/what-do-i-have-to-add-at-the-beginning-of-this-loop.)

But I'm unable to pick and open a particular file, say if the random node is 125, I'll open n125.txt file. Any help is appreciated. Here goes the code:

```
number_of_nodes=100;

for i=1:number_of_nodes

    rand_node=ceil(rand(1,1)*100);
    rand_output=ceil(rand(1,1)*10);  

    switch(rand_node)
        case{1}
            f1=fopen('n1.txt', 'a+');
            fprintf(f1, rand_output);
            fclose(f1);


       case{2}
            f2=fopen('n2.txt', 'a+');
            fprintf(f2, rand_output);
            fclose(f2)  ;

    end

end
```

Also, tried,
%..........................................

> Names = dir('myprog*.TXT');
>   Names.name; %returns all file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but the answer seems obvious:

```
 fid=fopen(sprintf('n%d.txt',rand_node), 'a+');
 fprintf(fid, rand_output);
 fclose(fid);
```

Comment: You did not misunderstood my question. I wasn't familiar with 'sprintf' command. Thanks for your help.  fprintf(fid, '%d',rand_output); works fine.